# XY Hamiltonian in a 1D Heisenberg Chain

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, matrix-representation

I've been trying to implement the 1D Heisenberg chain (i.e. the XXZ model) on Qiskit but have been having trouble. To recap, the Heisenberg hamiltonian is as follows:
$$H_{XXZ} = \sum^{N}_{i = 1} [J(S^{x}_{i}S^{x}_{i+1} + S^{y}_{i}S^{y}_{i+1} + \Delta S^{z}_{i}S^{z}_{i+1})] $$
and we can take the XY hamiltonian to be
$$H_{XY} = \sum^{N}_{i = 1} [J(S^{x}_{i}S^{x}_{i+1} + S^{y}_{i}S^{y}_{i+1})]$$
as I understand. I know that the matrix representation of this hamiltonian's time evolution takes the form
$$XY(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos[{\theta}/2] & i\sin[{\theta}/2] & 0\\
0 & i\sin[{\theta}/2] & \cos[{\theta}/2] & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
however, I'm not exactly sure how to implement it on Qiskit with the available Quantum logic gates. I do know that a special case to this problem is the iSwapGate, where it is equal to $XY(\theta = \pi)$, but is there a way to implement $XY(\theta)$ for arbitrary angles?

Comment: Are you wanting to implement the evolution of $H_{XY}$ over just two qubits, or over many qubits?

Comment: The two qubits case is the more important case for what I'm doing. However, the code I'm working on does generalize it to whatever number of sites/qubits I want. I had done so for the transverse Ising model before, so I think what I've done for this hamiltonian is correct as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, Parameter

theta = Parameter('θ')

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.crx(-1 * theta, 1, 0)
qc.cx(0, 1)

print(qc)
---
          ┌────────┐     
q_0: ──■──┤ RX(-θ) ├──■──
     ┌─┴─┐└───┬────┘┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤ X ├────■─────┤ X ├
     └───┘          └───┘
```

and to evaluate that it works:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

def XY(theta):
    c = np.cos(theta / 2)
    s = 1j * np.sin(theta / 2)
    
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], 
                     [0, c, s, 0], 
                     [0, s, c, 0], 
                     [0, 0, 0, 1]])

val = pi / 14
circ = qc.bind_parameters({theta: val})
np.allclose(Operator(circ).data, 
            XY(val))
---
True
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. I guess I need to look into the Qiskit library a bit more to get familiar with all of the available gates.